# SEO - Is it correct to say "optimize your code putting the JS code in the bottom of the page"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo, web-crawler

I'd like to know if this is an urban story or if is the truth.

I've heard that web crawlers, when they inspect a page on the web, terminate after an amount of time to catch the Available code (such html) and go to inspect another page. So, if the JS code is in the head, I'll lose a huge part of the reserved time for the catching.

If that's true, it is not good put the JS on the head, but maybe in the bottom, inside a jQuery syntax such `$(document).ready()`.

What can you tell me about this? Thanks everybody!

Comment: The JavaScript should be in a separate file so the crawler can decide if it wants to download it.

Comment: @Radek S while I agree in principal, sometimes you have to have it in the HTML.  @markzzz if you're messing with the DOM, it's always better to put it in a document ready block.

Comment: There's only two crawlers that matter anymore (Google and Bing), and neither reads just some small portion of your page then leaves. Unless you've purposely constructed the world's largest 500MB of HTML webpage, the whole thing is being read.

Comment: @Dan Yahoo! is used in Asia by many people. For the rest I totally agree.

Comment: Yahoo! doesn't run their own search engine anymore, it's just showing Bing results.

Comment: @Domenic : thanks for the edit. I know my english suck :)

Comment: But, can you give to me some examples of Crawlers that use this timing to catch the code of a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assertion that javascript should go at the end of the file is correct, but not really for the reason you state.

The primary reason for putting your javascript at the bottom of the file is that browsers try to render a page as it is being downloaded.  However, if javascript is encountered the browser will pause rendering to parse/run the javascript.  This can result in a user perception that the page is slow to load.  Putting the javascript at the end allows the browser to render the whole page (or most of it) before pausing to parse and process the javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether it's a myth or not, you should put your JavaScript at the bottom of the `<body>` in an external .js file. This means you don't have to use `$(document).ready` at all and the browser will only parse the JavaScript after loading the body content, which makes the page-loading faster. There is no point in putting the JavaScript in the `<head>`.

Comment: Really? As first thing when i learned about Javascript is this : put ALWASY the JS code in the head... haha! Paradox? :)

Comment: @markzzz If JS is in external file then it can be cached by browser. So when you open first page browser has to download html and js files but for next pages only html has to downloaded. So any JS code that can be used on several pages should go to external file.